# SQL Server 2008: Fill multiple T-SQL variables from one SELECT query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql

To fill one variable with a value from a query I can write following:

```
SET @TargetID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @bigDataSet ORDER BY date DESC)
```

To fill multiple variables from this query, eg. something like:

```
SET (@TargetID, @TargetName) = ....(SELECT TOP 1 ID, [Name] FROM @bigDataSet ORDER BY date DESC)
```

what can I write?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (1) @TargetID=ID, @TargetName=Name 
FROM @bigDataSet 
ORDER BY date DESC
```